# Why isn't my route loading?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and for some reason my routes isnt working, when I click on the test link. I have rechecked my code over and over and cant seem to find the problem.

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>



        <style>


        </style>

    </head>


    <body>


    <a href="#test">Test</a>

    <div ng-view></div>


    <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/test", {
            templateUrl : "test.html"
        })
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you have not given `ng-app="myApp"` in your html?

Comment: added as an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things I wanted to point out which you have missed.

1. You missed to kick off angular on page. You could do it by doing `ng-app="myApp"` as `myApp` module you already defined.
2. Other thing is, you have to change your `href` to `href="#/test"`, so that on click of link you will navigate to `/test` route

Comment: Ahh okay. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Define the module name in the view,

```
 <body ng-app="myApp">
```

Working [`App`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/98fksjhb/2/)